# Where does quicklisp save systems?

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp

After calling `(ql:quickload "system-name")`, and QuickLisp finishes downloading and installing the system, where on earth does it put it?

I tried looking in my project folder, but it wasn't there, and I couldn't find it in `~/quicklisp` either.

So where exactly does it save the system? If it does so at all, that is.

Comment: `quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be in a directory similar to the following example:

```
/home/electric/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/lparallel-20141106-git
```

To pick that apart: the Quicklisp client is designed so that users can create and add their own software repositories. Quicklisp calls these repositories `dists`. Quicklisp provides its own dist, which is also named `quicklisp`. In addition to the `software` in a dist, quicklisp also stores the dist's metadata and zipped software archives in the dist's directory. Separate from dists, the toplevel quicklisp directory also holds quicklisp's source, a place to put local-projects, and etc.

That's how you end up with the initially redundant looking `quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/`.

Also, `(ql:where-is-system 'system-name)` will return the system's location.

Answer (score 4):

Normally when you install quicklisp like this http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/#installation you should have this folder in your home directory.

/home/yourusername/quicklisp

and then you can find your installed libraries in

/home/yourusername/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software

and also you can add local asd file system in

/home/youusername/quicklisp/local-projects

maybe you install it when you were a superuser, to find this I think that you must use the shell command find to find the folder like in my fedora computer I did. here is the sample

```
sudo find / -name quicklisp
```

answer

```
Swipe your finger across the fingerprint reader
/home/anquegi/quicklisp
/home/anquegi/quicklisp/quicklisp
/home/anquegi/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp
/home/anquegi/.cache/common-lisp/abcl-1.3.1-fasl42-linux-x64/home/anquegi/quicklisp
/home/anquegi/.cache/common-lisp/abcl-1.3.1-fasl42-linux-x64/home/anquegi/quicklisp/quicklisp
/home/anquegi/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.2.4-1.fc21-linux-x64/home/anquegi/quicklisp

/home/anquegi/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.2.4-1.fc21-linux-x64/home/anquegi/quicklisp/quicklisp
/home/anquegi/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.2.4-1.fc21-linux-x64/home/anquegi/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp
/home/anquegi/lib/lisp/quicklisp
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: S’ha denegat el permís
```